# Pip3 install doesn't install the numpy module

Tags: python, numpy, pip

Installing the numpy module via conventional means (i.e. `sudo -H pip3 install --user numpy==1.17`) doesn't allow one to use the module.

Importing numpy is not possible nor is it listed in pip3 freeze

To solve this I use `sudo -E pip3 install --upgrade numpy` which then allows me to use the module and I can also see it in the list when i enter pip3 freeze.

Though this the problem is kind of solved for numpy it doesn't work for other python modules e.g. `configparser 3.8.1`.

This is what I have done thus far

```
 sudo -H pip3 install --user matplotlib


Collecting matplotlib
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/61/465fb3bfba684b0f53b5c4829c3c89e86e6fe9fdcdfda93e38f1788090f0/matplotlib-3.0.3-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (13.0MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 13.0MB 20.1MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10.0 in /root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.16.0)
Collecting pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 (from matplotlib)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/11/fa/0160cd525c62d7abd076a070ff02b2b94de589f1a9789774f17d7c54058e/pyparsing-2.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (65kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 35.8MB/s 
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1 (from matplotlib)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/18/4cd2e84c6aff0c6a50479118083d20b9e676e5175a913c0ea76d700fc244/kiwisolver-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (90kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 39.6MB/s 
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.1 (from matplotlib)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/17/c62faccbfbd163c7f57f3844689e3a78bae1f403648a6afb1d0866d87fbb/python_dateutil-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (226kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 235kB 56.2MB/s 
Collecting cycler>=0.10 (from matplotlib)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f7/d2/e07d3ebb2bd7af696440ce7e754c59dd546ffe1bbe732c8ab68b9c834e61/cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib) (20.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.1->matplotlib) (1.10.0)
Installing collected packages: pyparsing, kiwisolver, python-dateutil, cycler, matplotlib
Successfully installed cycler-0.10.0 kiwisolver-1.1.0 matplotlib-3.0.3 pyparsing-2.4.2 python-dateutil-2.8.0









Then enter


 pip3 freeze





blinker==1.3
chardet==2.3.0
cloud-init==19.1
command-not-found==0.3
configobj==5.0.6
cryptography==1.2.3
hibagent==1.0.1
idna==2.0
Jinja2==2.8
jsonpatch==1.10
jsonpointer==1.9
language-selector==0.1
MarkupSafe==0.23
numpy==1.17.1
oauthlib==1.0.3
prettytable==0.7.2
pyasn1==0.1.9
pycurl==7.43.0
pygobject==3.20.0
PyJWT==1.3.0
pyserial==3.0.1
python-apt==1.1.0b1+ubuntu0.16.4.5
python-debian==0.1.27
python-systemd==231
PyYAML==3.11
requests==2.9.1
six==1.10.0
ssh-import-id==5.5
ufw==0.35
unattended-upgrades==0.1
urllib3==1.13.1




Then enter


sudo -E pip3 install --upgrade matplotlib



Then enter 

 pip3 freeze



blinker==1.3
chardet==2.3.0
cloud-init==19.1
command-not-found==0.3
configobj==5.0.6
cryptography==1.2.3
cycler==0.10.0
hibagent==1.0.1
idna==2.0
Jinja2==2.8
jsonpatch==1.10
jsonpointer==1.9
kiwisolver==1.1.0
language-selector==0.1
MarkupSafe==0.23
matplotlib==3.0.3
numpy==1.17.1
oauthlib==1.0.3
prettytable==0.7.2
pyasn1==0.1.9
pycurl==7.43.0
pygobject==3.20.0
PyJWT==1.3.0
pyparsing==2.4.2
pyserial==3.0.1
python-apt==1.1.0b1+ubuntu0.16.4.5
python-dateutil==2.8.0
python-debian==0.1.27
python-systemd==231
PyYAML==3.11
requests==2.9.1
six==1.10.0
ssh-import-id==5.5
ufw==0.35
unattended-upgrades==0.1
urllib3==1.13.1
```

I expected to be able to use the modules directly after pip3 install however they aren't listed in the pip3 freeze list

Comment: you can try using a virtual environment?

Comment: Don't do both `sudo` and `--user`. Use just `--user`. With sudo you install the package into the whole system (really NOT recommended), but `--user` makes it install for current user - while under sudo, it probably messes everything up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have installed multiple versions of numpy. First try to remove them all

```
 sudo apt-get remove numpy
```

or

```
 pip3 uninstall numpy
```

then reinstall it again

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Anaconda, it also includes a lot of packages which can be useful for your work.